# Silverlight, RIA Services, MVC2P2 = No Data

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, asp.net-mvc-2, wcf-ria-services

I am having trouble upgrading my current project to use RIA Services. I added all the necessary web.config changes but still no luck. I everything compiles fine but when I hit the page using the datacontext I get an error. I debugged with fiddler and I'm getting a 404 on one of the request. I am getting back headers in my grid so some communication is happening but no data is actually coming through. Another thing to note is that my MVC is running windows authentication. I do have a clientaccesspolicy.xml as well.

Error in Silverlight with Headers but no data,
[image]

Response from Fiddler:

> [HttpException]: The controller for
>   path
>   '/Services/EpicWeb-Services-LegacyDomainService.svc/binary'
>   was not found or does not implement
>   IController.    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType)
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName)
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   httpContext)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   httpContext)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like all I needed was an IgnoreRoute.
First attempt was a typo.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allsvc}", new { allsvc = @".*\.svc(/.*)?" });
```

Comment: OneSmartGuy - you are one smart guy!  I was struggling with this very thing myself and your solution also corrected my issue!  Thanks alot!

Comment: I wish I could upvote you more than once...this saved me a helluva lot of time...