# Deployment Error: Silverlight 4.0 w/WCF RIA Services in ASP.NET MVC 2 App

Tags: deployment, asp.net-mvc-2, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I've got an MVC 2 App with an RIA Services link to a Silverlight Application.  The public facing portion of my site will be strictly MVC/HTML, but the administive portion will be silverlight (hosted in an MVC view page with data coming from RIA Services).  On my development machine, all is well, but when I deploy to Discount ASP servers, neither the MVC controller/view nor the WCF RIA services called from silverlight function:

A silverlight datagrid gets a load error:

> System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainOperationException: Load operation failed for query...  The remote server returned an error NotFound.

In the MVC page where I had a simple table that worked prior to adding an EF model and DomainDataSource, I now get the error:

> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

This is very similar to an issue I had before (with the beta versions of RIA Services & SL4 & MVC 2), but after upgrading from the beta to the release, the fix I had made before with respect to routing doesn't seem to work any longer.  The link for that issue is: [SL4/MVC2/WCF RIA Services = Load Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967670/silverlight-4-0-mvc-2-0-wcf-ria-services-ef-4-0-load-error)

I'm really struggling with deploying, and could use some help if anybody can shed any light on this.

Thanks!  Dennis

Comment: May I suggest installing Fiddler and also adding <customErrors mode="Off" /> into your web.config.  You'll get a lot of information out of Fiddler as I am currently struggling with the same issue.

Comment: Ardman - I did try fiddler but never got anything out of it... I guess I should have looked into it a bit more but my patience wore thin and I simply bailed out on it and am now just going javascript.  I guess I could give it a try again with your web.config suggestion, but I don't want to deal with these issues in the upcomming versions (which are coming more frequently).

Answer (score 0):

Mvc 2 with Ria to Silverlight? Im having the same 404 problem.

One upon a time I fixed the problem by telling my rout's to ignore the svc's.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allsvc}", new { allsvc = @".*\.svc(/.*)?" });
```

Post beta, this ignore route trick no longer works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to deploy System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.EntityFramework to your webserver.

cyberwaelder

Comment: cyberwaelder - This didn't fix it.  I'm able to load the silverligth application and navigate to pages, but the RIA services stuff still doesn't work.  It gives me "Load operation failed for query, the remote server returned an error: NotFound".

Thanks anyway, though.  If you have any other ideas, please let me know.